# Can't connect to Wifi 5GHz with Broadcom Corporation BCM4311

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, broadcom

I am using b43 driver installed via synaptic package manager and I have loaded the module through command line  “modprobe -r b43 bcma”.

The wifi indicator on my pc light up and the wifi manager shows many available wifi networks but my 5GHz network is missing. All other mobile devices and workstation are connecting to this network without any issue.

I have tested `brcmsmac bcma` and `wl` module but only `b43` seems to work with my wireless card => `Broadcom Corporation BCM4311 802.11a/b/g [14e4:4312] (rev 01)` .

NOTE:
My PCI device is listed as supported => http://www.linuxwireless.org/en/users/Drivers/b43/#supported and I can connect to the same network with the same workstation if I boot with Windows 7.
I am trying to connect to router `Technicolor TC7200`.

Question:
It is obvious that the old b43 driver doesn't recognize the 5HGZ access point, is there any other approach how to get this work?

Answer (score 0):

5GHz is NOT supported by broadcom-wl or any other driver choice. Sorry, [but look here](http://www.broadcom.com/docs/linux_sta/README_6.30.223.248.txt)

Answer (score 0):

> 5GHz is NOT supported by broadcom-wl or any other driver choice.
>   Sorry, but look here

This is NOT TRUE. I have an Apple "Airport Extreme" card BCM4321MCA/BCM94321MC/BCM94321MCA.

LSPCI Reports:
05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM4321 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4328] (rev 01)

When I install the Ubuntu Kernel driver from 14.04 I can connect to 5Ghz networks . When I install the b43 driver I can not.

The kernel driver however does not wake up and causes a crash

Answer (score 0):

Yeah. I agree with you.

It is not a solution to install the broadcom pci card in the terminal of ubuntu. I try the commands according to the ububtu guide in the weblink of Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers. In this way, you only get a 2.4GHz not 5GHz.

In contrast, you can go to System Settings --> Software & Updates, choose the checkbox of Developer Options, then switch to Additional Drivers to select Using Broadcom 802.11 Linux STA wireless driver source from bcmwl-kernel-source(proprietary) and apply changes. After yo reboot your Macbook, you will get your 5GHz.

I think that the problem is that the native Ubuntu 16.04LTS does not inlude the Broadcom PCI card. So you need do it this way. The Ubuntu team may recognize the issue and include it in the future.